# How to compare files using 010 Editor, and bound with template variables

Tags: c, hex, diff, reverse-engineering, binaryfiles

I wrote a good template for my binary format, but now i want to compare two files and stash differences with in next format: TemplateVariableName TemplateVariableType valueFile1 valueFile2.
I added script and can get differences with 010.Compare method, but its provide only addresses of blocks with differences.

**Question:**

1. How I can map address which I get after Compare method and variables names and variables types from template?
2. Can I achieve that with 010 editor methods?

**Code:**

```c
int i, f1, f2; 
FileOpen( "C:\\temp\\test1" ); 
f1 = GetFileNum(); 
FileOpen( "C:\\temp\\test2" ); 
f2 = GetFileNum(); 
TCompareResults r = Compare( COMPARE_SYNCHRONIZE, f1, f2 ); 
for( i = 0; i < r.count; i++ ) { 
  Printf( "%d %Ld %Ld %Ld %Ld\n", r.record[i].type, r.record[i].startA, r.record[i].sizeA, r.record[i].startB, r.record[i].sizeB ); 
}
```

Comment: Post the script which "you added" and its output.

Comment: It`s just from 010 editor User Reference. https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/FuncTools.htm

Comment: int i, f1, f2;
    FileOpen( "C:\\temp\\test1" );
    f1 = GetFileNum();
    FileOpen( "C:\\temp\\test2" );
    f2 = GetFileNum();
    TCompareResults r = Compare( COMPARE_SYNCHRONIZE, f1, f2 );
    for( i = 0; i < r.count; i++ )
    {
  if(r.record[i].type == 0)
   continue;

         Printf( "%d %Ld %Ld %Ld %Ld\n", 
             r.record[i].type, 
             r.record[i].startA, 
             r.record[i].sizeA, 
             r.record[i].startB, 
             r.record[i].sizeB ); 
    }

Comment: Output: 1 216 16 216 16
1 272 9 272 9
1 300 1 300 1
1 480 1 480 1
1 500 14 500 14
1 1176 1 1176 1
1 1224 1 1224 1
1 1252 9 1252 9
1 1272 1 1272 1
1 1284 1 1284 1
1 1308 17 1308 17
1 1334 2 1334 2
1 3604 5 3604 5
1 4932 1 4932 1
1 4942 14 4942 14
1 4964 1 4964 1
1 4974 2 4974 2
1 51428 8 51428 8
1 53776 16 53776 16
1 54016 16 54016 16
1 54240 32 54240 32
1 56016 32 56016 32
1 58224 16 58224 16
1 61412 1 61412 1
1 61428 1 61428 1
1 61532 1 61532 1
1 61548 1 61548 1